# My Click Listner is not working in while m using a customAdapter in android

Tags: android

In this code if else condition not working

```
holder.transaction_history1 = (TextView)    
row.findViewById(R.id.textView_matrimonyaccount_single_row_transaction_history1);        


 holder.transaction_history = (TextView) 
 row.findViewById(R.id.textView_matrimonyaccount_single_row_transaction_history);    


 holder.transaction_history1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    

                    @Override    
                    public void onClick(View v) {    
                    if(info.transaction_history.equalsIgnoreCase("Confirm"))    

                        {    
                            holder.transaction_history1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
                            Intent intent2 = new Intent (context,MainActiviy.class);    
                            context.startActivity(intent2);    
                        }
                        else    
                        {     
                            Toast.makeText(context,"",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);    
                        }    

                    }    
                    });
```

Comment: Is only `else` condition is not working? then call `Toast.show()` to show Toast message which is currently missing in else block

Comment: check your imports..its must be `View.OnClickListener`..and put a log in side `on click()`  to know whether its working or not

Comment: Will you consider any feedback to answers ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
instead of writing this

```
info.transaction_history.equalsIgnoreCase("Confirm")
```

Your **If** condition may not be returning true so write

```
info.transaction_history.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Confirm")
```